# Change location.hash while reloading the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am keeping some info about filters that I use on the page in the `location.hash` so if a user sends a link to another user, he has the first one's filters applied. However I would like that if first user refreshes the page to clean `location.hash` and reset filters. First thing that I thought about was to clean the `hash` on `unload` event but it doesn't seem to work as I wanted.
The code:

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){ window.location.hash = ''; });
```

Cleans `location.hash` after pressing F5, but then it holds and I must press F5 again to refresh my page. So I wrote:

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){ window.location.hash = ''; window.location.reload(true); });
```

But it doesn't change anything.
I was also experimenting with `onbeforeunload` event, but in it's scope I cannot change the `hash`. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Got it to work using a timeout.

```
$(window).on('unload', function(){ 
    window.location.hash = ''; 
    setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(true); }, 0); 
});
```